# Do grep and cp treat "recursive" the same?

Tags: grep, cp, recursive

I'm having trouble with `grep`'s manner of interpreting "recursive" searching compared to `cp`. Maybe it's just that I use them differently.

In this, `grep` seems to interpret "recursive" differently from `cp`. Is that correct? (my question)

Per my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245606/grep-search-all-directories-with-filename-extension) to navigate through this on SO...

With files containing the `grep`-matched string:

```bsh
./file1.js
./file2.php
./inc/file3.js
./inc/file4.php
./inc.php/file5.php
```

```bsh
grep -R "find me" *.php
```

Returns:

```bsh
./file2.php
./inc.php/file5.php
```

...because `grep` wants to match both directories and files containing ".php"

But, if I use `cp` to copy recursively, say:

```bsh
cp -r inc/* ~/mywork/
```

Files in the "inc" folder will be copied, along with all directories et cetera, albeit not hidden files, regardless of whether they have "inc" in their name.

Do `grep` and `cp` have different meanings of "recursive" or do they treat "recursive" the same? Could someone help me understand how different path/file arguments are interpreted by `cp` and `grep` the same way?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136311/discussion-on-question-by-jesse-steele-do-grep-and-cp-treat-recursive-the-same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `grep` command,

```bsh
grep -R "find me" *.php
```

... contains a filename globbing pattern, `*.php`.  This will be expanded by the shell before the shell executes `grep`, so the actual command at execution may look something like

```bsh
grep -R "find me" file1.php file2.php inc.php
```

... where `inc.php` happens to be a directory name.

The `grep` utility would then search the given files for the expression that you provided.  For directories mentioned on the command line, it would search *all* files and subdirectories beneath the directory for files with contents matching the expression.  This means you would have found a match in `inc.php/subdir/README` had that file contained the string `find me`.

In short: Process (search for matching lines within) each name given on the command line according to the given options (recursively).

The `cp` command works the same way with regards to recursive actions:

```bsh
cp -r inc/* ~/mywork/
```

The shell would expand the above command to something like

```bsh
cp -r inc/file1 inc/file2 inc/dir1 inc/dir2 /home/myself/mywork/
```

The `cp` utility would then, for each individually named file or directory, copy that file or directory recursively to the destination directory.

In short: Process (copy to destination) each name given on the command line according to the given options (recursively).

---

Additional notes:

- The support in `grep` for searching recursively is a non-standard extension.
- Filename globbing patterns that may expand to names starting with a dash should be handled with care to not be confused with command-line options.  Your `grep` command is, therefore, more safely written as

  ```bsh
  grep -R -- "find me" *.php
  ```

  or as

  ```bsh
  grep -R -e "find me" -- *.php
  ```

  ... where `--` delimits the options and their arguments from the non-option operands.  Your `cp` command does not have that issue, as the globbing pattern is guaranteed to expand to something starting with the string `inc/`.